# Throwing errors in ember components

Tags: ember.js

I was wondering what the best approach to throwing errors from components. In the following example I check if there an action passed and I throw an error to prevent further execution this works, however the error route is not triggered as I would of expected.

```
/**
         * Save step and go to the next step.
         */
        next() {
            if (isEmpty(this.get('nextAction'))) {
                throw new Error('The nextAction is undefined.');
            }
            if (isEmpty(this.get('saveAction'))) {
                throw new Error('The saveAction is undefined.');
            }
            const insuranceApplication = this.get('model');
            if (this.isLastDependent(this.get('dependentIndex'), insuranceApplication.get('dependents.length'))) {
                return this.get('nextAction')();
            }
            return this.get('saveAction')().then(() => {
                this.set('dependent', this.getNextDependent(insuranceApplication.get('dependents')));
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle error states using route templates. https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/#toc_code-error-code-substates.

But for a component you'll need to catch the error and assign it to a property of the component.

A simple example could be close to what you have already.

```
// component.js
if (isEmpty(this.get('nextAction'))) {
  this.set('error', 'The nextAction is undefined.');
}

// compontent.hbs
{{#if error}}
  Error: {{error}}
{{/if}}
```